# PHP cookies: does not have data on first execution?

Tags: php, cookies, session-cookies

I don't understand this as it seems strange to me - cookies: does not have data that I set when it is on the first execution.

My code,

```
$booking_time = '12:00';

$timeslots = array(
    array(
        "12:00",
        "12:30",
        "13:00",
        "13:30",
        "14:00",
        "14:30"
    ),
    array(
        "15:00",
        "15:30",
        "16:00",
        "16:30",
        "17:00",
        "17:30"
    )
);
//print_r($timeslots);

$selected_timeslot_start = null;
$selected_timeslot_end = null;
$selected_date = '2013-10-30';

foreach($timeslots as $index => $timeslot)
{
    if(in_array($booking_time, $timeslot)) 
    {
        $selected_timeslot_start = $timeslot[0].':00'; // first item.
        $selected_timeslot_end = end($timeslot).':00'; // last item
        //echo 'from = '.$timeslot[0];
        //echo ' to = '.end($timeslot);
        //print_r($timeslot);

        setcookie("selected_timeslot_start", $selected_timeslot_start, time()+1800 , '/');
        setcookie("selected_timeslot_end", $selected_timeslot_end, time()+1800 , '/');
        setcookie("selected_date", $selected_date, time()+1800 , '/');

    }
}
print_r($_COOKIE);
```

I get this,

```
Array
(
    [__atuvc] => 46|39
    [PHPSESSID] => olvlb3sv6bscvbpkva4d9ev6p3
)
```

Then I hit refresh on the browser, I get all the data,

```
Array
(
    [__atuvc] => 46|39
    [PHPSESSID] => olvlb3sv6bscvbpkva4d9ev6p3
    [selected_timeslot_start] => 12:00:00
    [selected_timeslot_end] => 14:30:00
    [selected_date] => 2013-10-30
)
```

Why - can someone tell me what I have done incorrectly with cookies?

Comment: not strange, as the manual says **"Cookies will not become visible until the next loading of a page that the cookie should be visible for. To test if a cookie was successfully set, check for the cookie on a next loading page before the cookie expires. Expire time is set via the expire parameter. A nice way to debug the existence of cookies is by simply calling print_r($_COOKIE);. "** http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well for one thing you shouldn't being using apostrophes in the path parameter.. it should be

setcookie("selected_date", $selected_date, time()+1800 , **"/"**);

Other than that I see no error in how you're setting cookies or retrieving data. Try changing how your path is being set and let me know your result.

Comment: Great! Could you just vote my answer to be the correct answer please? @lauthiamkok

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is correct behavior, when you set cookie, it will be send to the client (browser) and set, so, the first time cookie is set, and browser not send-back any cookie to the server, while for the second time, browser will include cookie within HTTP REQUEST Header, therefore, you will see complete data.

PHPSESSID is related to session, you might used it before.

Answer (score 0):

cookie is saved on the client and set by the browser.when you send a http request to the webserver,the browser will get the cookie of request's domain send to the webserver(cookie contained in http header);the webserver will return a response message,the header possible include cookie information like this:

```
Set-Cookie: set_cookie=set_value
```

then the browser will set the cookie and save it.
funciton setcookie just add the cookie information to the http response message's header.